# Why is my ionic code not working properly

Tags: ionic-framework

```
1. Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/geoloaction--save

2.Error: Cannot find module '@angular/tsc-wrapped/src/tsc'
```

I am not getting solution of this two error plzzz help me..

Answer (score 0):

What npm version do you have? (`npm --version`)

Try updating npm first (`npm install npm@latest -g`)

Comment: my npm version is v6.10.3